# Categorical pull-backs and pasting laws

Tags: category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\cal C$ be a category with pull-backs. Is it always true that given two objects $X$,$Y\in \cal C$ then $X\times_{Y} Y\cong X$?

My guess is that we have to require at least that $\cal {C}$$(X,Y)$ is non-empty.

The second question is the following: if this holds true, may I always naively insert or cancel the term $\times_Y Y$ in a pull-back in wich X appears or should I take care of the existence of other maps?

Is what I have written so far true also for 2-categorical pull-backs?

Comment: (1) If $\mathcal{C} (X,Y) = \emptyset$, then it makes no sense to consider pullbacks $X\times_Y Y$.

 (2) If $Y\to Y$ is the identity morphism (I don't know why you expect this property to hold otherwise), then the claim is trivial. In this case you can see that the square below is a pullback.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @> f>> Y\\
@VVidV @VVidV\\
X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}$$

Comment: I was just a bit confused because I calculated a certain pull-back formally inserting terms like $\times_{Y} Y$ but I was not able to write the diagram down and get the result only using pasting laws. But you are right, it is probably easier than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pullbacks aren't an operation on objects; they are an operation on *diagrams*. While we often write $X \times_Z Y$ for pullbacks of the form
$$\begin{CD} X \times_Z Y @>p_1 >> X
\\ @VV p_0 V @VVg V
\\ Y @> f>> Z
\end{CD}
$$
strictly speaking it is an *abuse* of notation to do so, for two reasons:

- The pullback depends on $f$ and $g$, so it's somewhat of a lie to use notation that ignores them
- The pullback isn't just an object; the maps $p_0$ and $p_1$ are part of the data of a pullback as well

There is a third issue, in that we speak of "the" pullback, but in the usual way it's only well-defined *up to isomorphism*.

Anyways, the pullback of an isomorphism is an isomorphism; i.e. in the diagram above, if $g$ is an isomorphism, then so is $p_0$.